# Bolts framework task queue

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsoperationqueue, alamofire, bolts-framework

I'm developing an iOS app and have been looking into using Bolts framework by Parse (facebook) to manage network operations (using Alamofire for network requests).

I'm wondering if there is a good implementation/pattern out there for a task queue for Bolts. I need to have offline functionality and therefore I (think) need to have some sort of task queue so if the user is offline all of their save/create operations are saved (queued and persisted) and then executed once they have a network connection, also needed for retries of requests. I've looked at NSOperation queue so I may go that route although I like how Bolts does things with BFTask and would prefer to use that.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your problem, but I think that you mix up the purpose of NSOperation queue and BFTasks a little bit.

BFTasks are used in order to use and create asynchronous and synchronous methods/network requests in a cohesive and minimalistic way. For instance, suppose that would have to login a user, present a search view and then download user`s search query results.

In order to keep your app optimized and have the UI at 60fps you would need to run your network request asynchronously. Apparently, you would present search view only if user logged in (using your method) (this technique is called "async tasks in series") and then you would download search results using parallel async requests (Think about downloading movie artworks for a movie name query in iTunes. They start downloading at the same time, "in parallel" to each other, so user images are downloaded independently from each other). (Whereas this is one is called "async tasks in parallel").

As you can see from this example, we can only achieve the desired logic along with desired performance if we use sequential and parallel async requests.
Bolts framework allows you to achieve all of the aforementioned logic in a VERY cohesive and convenient way.

NSOperation queue, on the other hand, allow you to build a complex sequence of both sync and async methods. It even allows you to get the status of a particular operation and bind dependencies. A good example of it, is view controller lifecycle.

If I were you, I would first learn how to use Bolts and NSOperation queue apart from each other. Then, depending on what you actually need to achieve in your app in terms of functionality, I would start thinking about binding Bolts and NSOperation queue in a class or a struct (in case you use swift). Like using Bolts for "online" stuff (executing network requests) and NSOperation queue for "offline" (storing the sequence of actions the user makes while being offline, in order to execute this sequence when the internet connection is back).

You can read more about NSOperation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperation) and about Bolts for iOS [here](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS).

**UPDATE:**

In terms of implementation pattern, one suggestion that you might want to consider is to create a simple class/struct that would be responsible for storing("stacking") your Bolts methods. You can use arrays for sequential logic and sets for parallel one. You can also use sets to easily make sure that some of the requests happen only once as sets store only unique objects. Honestly, in my opinion, you should try to implement something similar to what I described, because Bolts itself (almost for sure) incorporates NSOperation and NSOperaitionQueue.

By the way, since [Parse iOS SDK is open source right now](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/open-sourcing-our-sdks/), you could see how they implement `saveEvenutually` method which saves an object when internet connection is back and think how you could replicate their logic according to your needs.

Comment: thanks for your input, i understand how each work on their one (and have used both independently) i was just looking for if there was already a good implementation out there to bind the two. Like an NSOperationQueue and instead of NSOperations have it be BFTasks.

Comment: Well, that is something that would extremely hard to find, because at this point there there is potentially a lot of specifics in terms of how exactly you want to bind these two things.

Comment: I have added several suggestions, see if any of them might help you out.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I've been taking a look at the parse sdk, lots to work through but I think I have a good starting point.